# How to store previous value into the array

Tags: c++, arduino

Hello guys I'm reading incoming values from analog pin. And I need to store previous values into the array.

Code which I'm using:

```
int u = A0;
int y = A1;
float z[4][1] = {{0},      
                {0}, 
                {0},     
                {0}};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(u, INPUT);
  pinMode(y, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    u = analogRead(A0);
    y = analogRead(A1);
}
```

How can I do this?

```
z[4][1] = {{u(n-1)},      
           {u(n-2)}, 
           {y(n-1)},     
           {y(n-1)}};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a second dimension of length `[1]`? Why not just `float z[4]`?

Comment: what is "the previous value" ? for an `int` this: `u(n-1)` is not valid syntax, so you need to explain a bit more what you mean. Perhaps you just want to store the values you read in `loop` and then `u` and `y` are your "previous values" ?

Comment: because it was part of my assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to copy the values. As mentioned in a comment why is the second dimension 1? I have left that one out.

How I usually do it is:

```
 z[1] = z[0];
 z[0] = u;
 z[3] = z[2];
 z[2] = y;
```

this will shift the previous value into the other value of the matrix, to put it in your code:

```
int pinU = A0;
int pinY = A1;
int u = 0;
int y = 0;
float z[4] = {0,0,0,0}

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(pinU, INPUT);
   pinMode(pinY, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    u = analogRead(A0);
    y = analogRead(A1);
    z[1] = z[0];
    z[0] = u;
    z[3] = z[2];
    z[2] = y;

}
```

This wil effectively make z = {u(n), u(n-1), y(n), y(n-1)}

Comment: Thank you, z was part of my assignment. I'll just adjust it for my assignment

Comment: @Franta123456 If it helped please accept either Batuhan Orhan 's or my answer. Further it is strange that one would make a 2 dimensional array with second dimension indicating only 1 element But I guess it's to get the Transposed Array for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. I tried this on simulation and it worked well. You can see data changes on serial monitor. storeValues() function does what you want. you need to call it first in loop function.

```
int firsPin = A0;
int secondPin = A1;
int u = 0, y = 0, lastU = 0, lastY = 0;

//0 : u(n-1) 1 : u(n-2) 2 : y(n-1) 3 : y(n-2) 
int z[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(firsPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(secondPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  storeValues();
  u = analogRead(firsPin);
  y = analogRead(secondPin);    
  Serial.println("u: " + String(u));
  Serial.println("y: " + String(y));
  Serial.println("u(n-1): " + String(z[0]));
  Serial.println("y(n-1): " + String(z[2]));
  Serial.println("u(n-2): " + String(z[1]));
  Serial.println("y(n-2): " + String(z[3]));
  delay(100);
}

void storeValues() {
  z[1] = z[0];
  z[3] = z[2];
  z[0] = u;
  z[2] = y;
}
```